# POST method in gae-boilerplate

Tags: python, google-app-engine, boilerplate

I am using [gae-boilerplate](https://github.com/coto/gae-boilerplate) to build my simple web app on GAE, I have noticed that in order to make my post request handler to be invoked, I need to add one hidden filed in my form, it is:

```
<input type="hidden" name="_csrf_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

If I didn't add this line, I will get 403 error, this is because the following check (within dispatch method in BaseHandler) in gae-boilerplate:

```
if self.request.method == "POST" and not self.request.path.startswith('/taskqueue'):
    token = self.session.get('_csrf_token')
    if not token or token != self.request.get('_csrf_token'):
        self.abort(403)
```

It is fine when the form is generated in GAE, the csrf_token() will be generated correctly. Now, my question is:

**When I try to send a post request (actually, it is json not form data) from mobile app, how can I know what _csrf_token should be setup in this request?**

Sorry, I am not familiar to how the session/csrf_token work in web. If I add code to bypass the token check, is it a bad idea for some security reason?

Comment: I also dont understand this! They want us to route all our post request to go through taskqueue

Comment: Hi specialscope, I don't think they want all post requests go through taskqueue. Just _csrf_token can be skipped in post request to path '/taskqueue'. Anyway, I finally just didn't use gae-b directly, only use it when I need something to reference to...

Comment: Ya good call, I am also using modified version of BaseHandler.